# How to make a GUI interface for a discord bot made using python?

Tags: discord.py

*I have made a simple bot in python for discord and it is working pretty well but I want a GUI to load when I run the script that will have some buttons to tune the bot. How do i do this? I am quite new to this and I can't find a answer.

Edit-
I tried to use tkinter but the problem is either the bot works or the gui both don't work simultaneously. I want the bot script and GUI to work together not one after another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those working with Python development, there are several frameworks and tools that allow the creation of graphical interfaces.

The following are some graphical frameworks that allow you to develop Python interfaces:

```
WxWidgets;
Tkinter;
Kivy;
PyGTK;
PySide;
QT.
```

Tkinter comes standard by default on most Python installations, so all we have to do is import the library.

To import the entire contents of the module we use the following command:

```py
from tkinter import *
```

I suggest you read this tutorial: https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/

Comment: I tried this but the problem is only one is working either the bot or the GUI but I want both to work at the same time

Comment: The application structure must be controlled by the gui. You must tie links (triggers) from your program to the gui controls. The operating flow must be one. It would be interesting if you made the code available for analysis. If you want, contact us: faguiro2005@gmail.com